# Tuning SVM parameters in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, svm

I am training an SVM model for the classification of the variable V19 within my dataset.

I have done a pre-processing of the data, in particular I have used MICE to impute some missing data.
Anyway a part of the training dataset I use is this one:

[image: training-set]

Through the "tune" function I tried to train looking for the best parameters through cross-validation;

```
tune.out <- tune(svm, hard~., data=train, kernel="sigmoid",type="C",decision.values =TRUE,scaled =TRUE, ranges=list(cost=2^(-3:2),gamma=2^(-25:1),coef0=1^(-15:5)),tunecontrol = tune.control(nrepeat = 5, sampling = "cross", cross = 5))
```

I tried many combinations of parameters and different kernels, but what I get is always a model that can not predict correctly even the same training data, always returns all outputs to FALSE.

I really don't know if it's just a problem of tuning parameters or if I managed wrong the dataset.

Thanks for any advice.

EDIT : @Alex H I tried your code and what I obtain is :

```
Support Vector Machines with Radial Basis Function Kernel 
1094 samples
  18 predictor
   2 classes: 'X1', 'X2' 

Pre-processing: centered (18), scaled (18) 
Resampling: Cross-Validated (10 fold, repeated 5 times) 
Summary of sample sizes: 985, 985, 985, 985, 984, 984, ... 
Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  C     ROC        Sens    Spec
  0.25  0.5241539  0.9996  0   
  0.50  0.5320540  1.0000  0   
  1.00  0.5066151  0.9994  0   
  2.00  0.5225485  1.0000  0   
  4.00  0.5130391  1.0000  0   

Tuning parameter 'sigma' was held constant at a value of 0.04595822
ROC was used to select the optimal model using the largest value.
The final values used for the model were sigma = 0.04595822 and C = 0.5.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the caret package.

```
library(caret)
set.seed(12345)

#Create simulation data
topxdata = matrix(rnorm(200, mean=0, sd=1), nrow = 20, ncol = 10)
botxdata = matrix(rnorm(200, mean=1, sd=1), nrow = 20, ncol = 10)
xdata = rbind(topxdata, botxdata)
colnames(xdata) = 1:10

ydata = c(rep("Top", 20), rep("Bottom", 20) )
ydata = as.factor(ydata)


# Setup for cross validation
ctrl <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv",   # 10fold cross validation
                     repeats=5,         # do 5 repetitions of cv
                     summaryFunction=twoClassSummary,   # Use AUC to pick the best model
                     classProbs=TRUE)


#Train and Tune the SVM
svm.tune <- train(x=xdata,
                  y= ydata,
                  method = "svmRadial",   # Radial kernel
                  tuneLength = 5,                   # 5 values of the cost function
                  preProc = c("center","scale"),  # Center and scale data
                  metric="ROC",
                  trControl=ctrl)

svm.tune
```

Post your result

````
Support Vector Machines with Radial Basis Function Kernel 

40 samples
10 predictors
 2 classes: 'Bottom', 'Top' 

Pre-processing: centered (10), scaled (10) 
Resampling: Cross-Validated (10 fold, repeated 5 times) 
Summary of sample sizes: 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, ... 
Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  C     ROC    Sens  Spec
  0.25  0.980  0.85  0.91
  0.50  0.975  0.85  0.90
  1.00  0.955  0.83  0.88
  2.00  0.945  0.82  0.84
  4.00  0.945  0.81  0.77

Tuning parameter 'sigma' was held constant at a value of 0.06064355
ROC was used to select the optimal model using the largest value.
The final values used for the model were sigma = 0.06064355 and C = 0.25.
```
````

Comment: Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Even with this solution I always obtain FALSE as prediction

Comment: @Marts your ROC values are basically 0.5, and your specificity=0. This means the classifier isn't able to distinguish the two classes. Try a different classifier (e.g. change to method = "rf"). If that doesn't work you might have to collect more data.

Comment: thanks. I tried svmRadialWeights and I obtain some results, now I'm playing with parameters. I have to use SVM for this homework, maybe I will try sigmoid kernel, but in Caret I didn't find it as method.